# Fibonacci sequences within the Fibonacci sequence recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to perform a runtime analysis of the following simple recursive Fibonacci number algorithm:

```
Fibonacci(n) {
    if n < 0 return -1
    else if n == 0 return 0
    else if n == 1 return 1
    else return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)
}
```

Define the "$T(i)$ count" for $n$ to be the number of times $T(i)$ is evaluated by the algorithm when evaluating $T(n)$.

In breaking down the formulas for smaller values of $n$, I found the following to be true:

| $n$ | $T(1)$ count | $T(0)$ count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 8 | 5 |
| 7 | 13 | 8 |

Note: $T(1)$ is the run time of the above algorithm when $n = 1$, and $T(0)$ is the run time of the algorithm when $n = 0$. Specifically, $T(1), T(0)\in \Theta(1)$.

The trend in the counts of $T(1)$s and $T(0)$s seems like they follow the Fibonacci sequence themselves:

- The number of $T(1)$s making up the run time of the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number itself, $F_n$.
- The number of $T(0)$s making up the run time of the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number is the $(n - 1)^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number, $F_{n-1}$, except for $F_0$ which has one $T(0)$ in its run time (I noticed that for $n = 0$ the number of $T(0)$s is the same as the number of $T(0)$s when $n = 2$ minus the number of $T(0)$s when $n = 1$, i.e., $T(0)$ count = $T(2)$ count $ - \text{ } T(1)$ count).

This would mean that

$$T(n) = F_n \times T(1) + F_{n - 1} \times T(0) \in \Theta\left( F_n \right) \cup \Theta\left( F_{n-1} \right) = \Theta\left( F_n \right)$$

for $n \geq 1.$

I guess my only question regarding the work above is to ask someone if it's accurate. I'm very excited by this, so I'm hoping it's correct.

Thank you for your time, attention, and patience (I'm not sure if this is entirely in compliance with the rules, but I'm so amazed by this that I honestly just wanted to share it and determine if I'm right).

Comment: What are $T(0)$ and $T(1)$?

Comment: I apologize, I should've defined those. $T(0)$ is the run time of the algorithm when $n = 0$, and $T(1)$ is the run time of the algorithm when $n = 1$. Specifically, $T(0), T(1) \in \Theta(1)$.

Comment: I do not follow. The run time of the algorithm when $n=0$ should just be a single number, not a sequence, shouldn't it? Also, how are you defining run time?

Comment: Do you mean that "$T(0)$ count" is the number of times Fibonacci$(0)$ is evaluated?

Comment: For $n\geq 1$ it seems to follow a Fibonacci sequence. For $n = 0$, $T(n) \in \Theta(1)$.

Comment: Yes, $T(0) \text{ count}$ is the number of times it appears in the final broken down formula.

Comment: Also, I'm specifying run time in terms of the index value $n.$ I'm not sure if this is the proper terms to specify run time, I think it's similar to what I learned in my algorithms course though.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear.  From the line `return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)` you can show that the $T(0)$ count and the $T(1)$ count both obey the Fibonacci recurrence and then the formula for them follows.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. Just to make sure I fully understand, the $T(0)$ and $T(1)$ count values *do* follow a Fibonacci sequence themselves?

Comment: Yes, they are Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much! So exciting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct, by induction. We see that the count of Fibonacci(1) evaluations is $F_n$ for $n=1,2$. Then assuming the (strong) inductive hypothesis that
`Fibonacci(k)` evaluates `Fibonacci(1)` $F_k$ times for $0<k<n$, we see from the line `return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)` that `Fibonacci(n)` evaluates `Fibonacci(1)` $F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} = F_n$ times, and similarly counts of evaluations of `Fibonacci(0)` obeys the Fibonacci recurrence relation. Similarly, for any $i$ we see that eventually (after some initial conditions) the count of `Fibonacci(i)` evaluations obeys the Fibonacci recurrence.